# Spin group for the complexified Clifford algebras

Tags: automorphism-group, clifford-algebras

The $Spin(p,q)$ group is usually defined as
$$
Spin(p,q) = \{s \in C\ell^{+}_{p,q}: s \tilde{s}=1\}
$$
where $s$ belongs to the Lipschitz group and $C\ell^{+}_{p,q}$ denotes the even element subset of the Clifford algebra with signature $(p,q)$. Since in this definition the Clifford algebra is defined over the reals, the tilde in $\tilde{s}$ simply refers to inverting the order of the elements inside $s$.

**I have two questions:**

1. Does this definition for the tilde still work for the Spin group definition if I consider instead the complexified Clifford algebra? I.e., is this definition correct:
   $$
   Spin(p,q) = \{s \in \mathbb{C}\otimes C\ell^{+}_{p,q}: s \tilde{s}=1\} \, ?
   $$
   My intuition says that $\tilde{s}$ should be redefined as the elements in inverse order followed by a complex conjugation of the coefficients contained in it, i.e. it should actually appear as $\tilde{s}^*$ in the definition of the Spin group, by I'm not sure of this.
2. Is there still a Triality automorphim in the case of the $Spin(8,0)$ group considering complex coefficients?

Thanks!